# Question about wifi connection files/certificates

Tags: wireless

Here is the output i get when i run my school's wifi .py file for secure login.

I "python SecureW2_JoinNow.py"

I've emailed them about it, but wanted to take a shot and post here, could be on my end.

I can't make sense of this error, although the last line makes me think it's on my end.

Fresh install, so maybe that is it...

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SecureW2_JoinNow.py", line 252, in <module>
    main()
  File "SecureW2_JoinNow.py", line 248, in main
    nm.connect()
  File "SecureW2_JoinNow.py", line 196, in connect
    wireless_device = nm_iface.GetDeviceByIpIface('wlan0')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.UnknownDevice: No device found for the requested iface.
```

Comment: Is more likely their fault (or yours) for not using python correctly, also we may need to see the actual file (lines 190-260) to see what they (or you) are doing wrong.

Comment: I_am - you appear to have multiple accounts.  Please register one of these accounts.  Then click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page to request your other accounts are merged.  Once done, you'll then be able to add additional information to your question.  Thanks.